# How to add Scroll Pane dynamically into the Tabbed Pane in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am Working on Swing application and i need to add Dynamically Scroll pane into the Tabbed Pane and I need to add Jpanel into the each Scroll pane. so how can i add it i have tried one code but its not adding Scroll pane. can i have help.

Here my code is.

```
public class ChatDialog_Tabbedpane extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static JLabel jLabelchat;
    int i= 0;

    public ChatDialog_Tabbedpane() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            System.out.println(jTextArea1.getText());
            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();

            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
            jsp.add(jPanel);
            jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, 1));
            i++;
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(i+" :label 2"));

            jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab", jPanel);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                     
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new ChatDialog_Tabbedpane().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

its looking like this

but not showing scroll i just need to add all time That pane when Send button is clicked.
  and how can i get it using unique identify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `add` with `JScrollPane`, use `setViewportView` instead, for example...

```
jsp.setViewportView(jPanel);
```

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

A component may only reside within a single contaniner, when you do something like...

```
jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab", jPanel);
```

You are removing the `jPanel` from it's previous parent (the `JScrollPane`), instead, add the scroll pane to the tabbed pane...

```
jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab", jsp);
```

Comment: its not adding still sp.setViewportView(jPanel); that we have to add in last ? i mean when data is added to Jpanel? or in first?

Comment: so panel will be added in jscroll pane?

Comment: The panel will be set as view component for the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewport`, but essentially, yes...

Comment: okey :) i got it and its works too :) and ya i have one more question

Comment: okey and if i want to fatch i mean access that panel inside that scrollpane then how can i do it. i mean we add more then one jscroll pane in that and if i want to access one of the jpanel inside jscroll pane how can i do it? let say i want to access which is active now.

Comment: You going to need some kind of access control, maybe a list or `Map` or better yet some custom component that is capable of managing all this

Comment: and how can i use it. i mean i need to add new jlabel into the panel which is active and how can i get that component ?